# What do I benchmark before updating a web site?

Tags: web-development, client-relations, benchmarking

I am volunteering my time to update a website for a local business. The current website they have is not up to date and it fails quite a few "web tests".

For example, the pages are too large, the images are not compressed, and the site is not mobile friendly.

All of these things are measurable - eg. the time taken to load (in seconds), bandwidth (in kb), and a list of the devices the site displays correctly on. It is my intention to note these benchmarks before starting the project, and upon completion.

My question is: what benchmarks do web developers present to their clients?

Answer (score 3):

- SEO. Most clients don't care about technical details of a website.
  They want people to come to the website so it has to appear near the
  top of search result. They'd pay a lot for this. Maybe the website
  doesn't need to change, just need to be advertised.
- User Experience. After people visits the website, they need to be converted into customers.    This can be technical, stuff like page latency, responsive design, etc. It can also be the design itself which could require overhaul.

So, instead of benchmarks, try analyse logs and install analytics if there's not one installed yet and see if updating would improve the bottom line.

Comment: +1. Good point. The actual thing which matters is visitors themselves. Any other element is just here to help improving visitors experience. The customer doesn't care about if it takes 59 ms. or 266 ms. to load a page, unless visitors are leaving the website they feel slow. The customer doesn't care about browsers support, unless half of the visitors use smartphones and the website looks broken on smartphones. There are plenty of other examples.